# Can't get rid of repeats in mysql query

Tags: mysql

I'm completing some queries for my databases class and I've ran into one that I can't seem to get.

It says: "For the student with ID "20084" (or any other value) show the total number of credits for the courses taken. Don't display the tot_creds value from the student table, you should use SQL aggregation on courses taken by the student."

I have looked for some answers online but none of them truly convinced me and basically all of them gave me different results.

I've got this on my own:

```
select    sum(credits)
from      (course join section using(course_id)) join (takes join student using(ID))
          using (course_id, sec_id, semester, year)
where student.ID = 20084;
```

The problem I have is that the student has repeated a couple courses and the query returns the credits of those repeated courses as well. I've tried putting `distinct` in front of `sum(credits)` but the answer is the same.
Is there anything I'm missing?
Thanks.

[image: The model I have to work with.]

Comment: `takes join student using(ID)` ?? no student_id in table takes?

Comment: Both takes and student have "ID"

Comment: Shouldn't there be a column that indicated if the course was completed? There should be data to indicate if the credits are earned or not.

Comment: That'd be ideal but this is what I have to work with.

Comment: I've updated my answer below. I suspect that the **`takes`.`grade`** column would determine if the student passed the course or not, and if credit is earned. The change I made would include only credits for the highest grade earned. The where clause could be altered so it includes only credits above a certain value. This would provide a more accurate result because there may be rows in takes where the course wasn't repeated, and the credits aren't earned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should return what you are looking for. In the sub-select, I used MAX() even though the values of repeated items would be the same just so it would return one result from repeated rows. This sub select will return one row for each instance of a course, so the sum of that would not include the repeated courses.

```
SELECT
    SUM(`a`.`credits`) as `credits`
FROM (
    SELECT
        MAX(`course`.`credits`) AS `credits`
    FROM `student`
    JOIN `takes` 
        ON `takes`.`ID` = `student`.`ID`
    JOIN `section`
        USING (`course_id`,`sec_id`,`semester`,`year`)
    JOIN `course`
        ON `course`.`course_id` = `section`.`course_id`
    WHERE `student`.`ID` = 20084
    GROUP BY `section`.`course_id`
    ORDER BY `takes`.`grade` DESC
    ) AS `a`
```

To test the sub-query, try running this query. It should return a list of all courses taken, with just one row per course:

```
SELECT
    `section`.`course_id`,
    `section`.`sec_id`,
    `section`.`semester`,
    `section`.`year`,
    MAX(`course`.`credits`) AS `credits`
FROM `student`
JOIN `takes` 
    ON `takes`.`ID` = `student`.`ID`
JOIN `section`
    USING (`course_id`,`sec_id`,`semester`,`year`)
JOIN `course`
    ON `course`.`course_id` = `section`.`course_id`
WHERE `student`.`ID` = 20084
GROUP BY `section`.`course_id`
ORDER BY `takes`.course_id`,`takes`.`grade` DESC
```

Comment: This query would be easy to modify to show the credits for all students.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help but it doesn't work. Checked it a couple times maybe I had copied it wrong. Returns "Error Code 1248. Every derived table must have its own alias"

Comment: I added an alias to the sub-query. Try it again.

Comment: Same thing, sorry.

Comment: Same number of credits as the ones my query gets. I checked the data myself looking for all the courses the student has. It includes repeats.

Comment: See the 2nd query above and look at the results to see if there are any repeats.

Comment: Tried it. It works but it also returns an extra row with a repeated course.https://imgur.com/a/oyMjK I'm attaching a screencap of yours and one of the actual courses with their respective credits.

Comment: Run the 2nd query. The results should show what is being repeated - it returns more than one column, 5 columns to be specific

Comment: It's repeating course ID 960 2 times. The result should be 65 and it returns 68.

Comment: It's solved now. Thank you very much. Extremely helpful.

Comment: Glad to help. Be sure to accept the answer since it's working now.